# Javascript - getting element box-shadow details accurately

Tags: javascript, css, zepto

I have come a bit unstuck..

Well near enough every css property has seperate parts IE.

```
margin-left
border-top-color
transition-duration
```

However, I have searched around a bit and it seem's to me that this is not the case with `box-shadow`.
For example i have 4 `<input>`'s, the `H Spread` **&** `V Spread` **&** `Blur` **&** `Color`. and i wan't to change a elements box shadow on change of these fields. After finding out that there isn't any specifics on box shadow, i decided that the best way would be to split the `box-shadow` into a `Array` using something like this

```
element.style.boxShadow.split(' ');
```

However the result does not come back in the right order as shown in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HQ7NF/1)

```
<div id="test" style="box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #999;"> Welcome </div>
console.log( element.style.boxShadow.split(' ') );
```

Is resulting in this output `["rgb(153,", "153,", "153)", "1px", "1px", "3px"]`

The color is different and the order has changed which doesn't sound very reliable to me.

Is there a way we can acuratelly get/set the different sections of a `box-shadow`

I am also using Zepto.js if there is a solution there.

I have tried `.css();` = same result.

Comment: is there a reason you wouldn't just change the class and have that new style defined in CSS?

Comment: Yes. I'm making a webpage builder @kalley, you have input's that would change the element's `box-shadow`.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-css3-background-20080910/#the-box-shadow

Comment: @Esailija and how is that supposed to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will help you get toward your goal. I made a regex, that matches what the browser is outputting (the rgb is just the hex as an rgb). It may need to be updated since I didn't test it in all browsers, but I think it converts it to rgb so if there is an alpha, that can be handled easily.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HQ7NF/2/

And here's the regex I am using:

```
var reBoxShadow = /(?:rgb\((\d+), ?(\d+), ?(\d+)\)([^,]*))+/g;
while ( style = reBoxShadow.exex(element.style.boxShadow) ) {
    /* this is where stuff happens */
}
```

I then split the color and the args into separate variables, so you can decide what to do with them. I hope that can at least get you on the right track.